# Safari el.clientHeight discrepancy, affected by stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, safari

While trying to determine the height of a number of divs, I came across a significant discrepancy with the result produced by Safari (v10.1.1) when calculating on the site's script load when compared with what the Safari inspector reports. So far, the issue hasn't surfaced in Chrome or Firefox.

In testing, I'm simply targeting one of the divs in question (which has a few child elements):

```
console.log(document.getElementById('foo1').clientHeight);
```

The result returned in the console for this particular div is 329, much larger than expected. However, when I review the node in Safari's inspector, the clientHeight is reported to be 175--which is the expected, accurate number. Similarly, if I run the same command directly in Safari's console command line, the correct number is returned.

With some further testing, it appears as though my stylesheet is causing the issue because if I temporarily remove it the returned result is accurate.

Does anyone have any insight as to why this might be the case? I'm just surprised that the correct numbers are reported by Safari except when executed on script load and why the stylesheet might force the discrepancy. Is it possible that the loading order of the script and stylesheets as anything to do with the issue? Note that I'm loading my script at the bottom of the page, before the closing `</body>`

Cheers, and thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you set these styles ? From an `<link>` element ? Where is it in your doc ? It's all possible that it hasn't been parsed yet when you do call `clientHeight`: https://jsfiddle.net/vcjake8u/ waiting for `DOMContentLoaded` or even `load` events should fix it.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido--that seems to have worked. Previously tried firing on load, but was doing so incorrectly. Appreciate the nudge in the right direction. Cheers.